# XSLT for sorting elements of particular XML tags based on elements' attribute

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xpath

Want to transform(sort) "elements of Particular Tag"

I am new to XSLT. hence required to understand how particular tag can be handled by XSLT.

**Current XML**

```
<root>
    <tag>bla bla bla</tag>
    <tag>foo foo foo</tag>
    <tag>
         <particular-tag>
               <element attrib="2"/>
               <element attrib="3"/>
               <element attrib="4"/>
               <element attrib="1"/>
         </particular-tag>
         <particular-tag>
               <element attrib="5"/>
               <element attrib="3"/>
               <element attrib="4"/>
         </particular-tag>
    </tag>
</root>
```

**Desired XML**

```
<root>
    <tag>bla bla bla</tag>
    <tag>foo foo foo</tag>
    <tag>
         <particular-tag>
               <element attrib="1"/>
               <element attrib="2"/>
               <element attrib="3"/>
               <element attrib="4"/>
         </particular-tag>
         <particular-tag>
               <element attrib="3"/>
               <element attrib="4"/>
               <element attrib="5"/>
         </particular-tag>
    </tag>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance. You can suggest me online learning source where I can play with XML-XLST.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This XSLT will produce desired result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="particular-tag">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="@attrib"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: request for solution based on this question [Sorting cells as per ss:Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210819/sorting-cells-as-per-ssindex)

Answer (score -1):

This should produce the results you're looking for.
Hope it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="particular-tag">
    <particular-tag>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="element">
        <xsl:sort select="@attrib"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </particular-tag>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for solution & I replaced `<particular-tag>` with `<xsl:copy>`